# How to configure Helmet in a Nestjs project using Fastify?

Tags: nestjs, fastify, helmet.js, nestjs-fastify

I'm using **Nestjs** (7.x) and **Fastify** (with `@nestjs/platform-fastify`).
I'm trying to install **Helmet** in my project ([`fastify-helmet`](https://github.com/fastify/fastify-helmet)), but I'm not able to figure how to integrate/configure it with Nestjs. What's the proper way to have it onboard?

Here is my Nestjs bootstrap:

```js
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { FastifyAdapter, NestFastifyApplication } from '@nestjs/platform-fastify';
import { MainModule } from './main.module';
import * as helmet from 'fastify-helmet';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestFastifyApplication>(MainModule);
  await app.listen(3000, 0.0.0.0);
}
bootstrap();
```

Answer (score 6):

You've got two options when it comes to registering middleware for fastify. The first is to get the instance of the HttpAdapter and use the `register` method from there. This can be done like so:

```js
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import {
  FastifyAdapter,
  NestFastifyApplication,
} from '@nestjs/platform-fastify';
import * as helmet from 'fastify-helmet';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestFastifyApplication>(
    AppModule,
    new FastifyAdapter(),
  );
  app
    .getHttpAdapter()
    .getInstance()
    .register(helmet);
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

The other option is to pass the type to the `NestFactory.create` method and then use `app.register`. This can bee seen here

```js
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import {
  FastifyAdapter,
  NestFastifyApplication,
} from '@nestjs/platform-fastify';
import * as helmet from 'fastify-helmet';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestFastifyApplication>(
    AppModule,
    new FastifyAdapter(),
  );
  app.register(helmet);
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

Both ways are valid, though only the second option is type safe.

Comment: Thanks for your 2 solutions and your explanations. However in both way I'm still getting an error where *plugin must be a function or a promise*. Also does it mean that `app.getHttpAdapter().getInstance().register()` is the same as `app.register()` but typing here is managed differently?

Comment: Interesting. I tested both of these locally and had no problems with either set up. As for your question about if `app.register` is really `app.getHttpAdapter().getInstance().register`, the answer is yes. Nest just gives you the typings for it instead of having to go through the call chain.

Answer (score 1):

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import {
  FastifyAdapter,
  NestFastifyApplication,
} from '@nestjs/platform-fastify';
import { fastifyHelmet } from 'fastify-helmet';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestFastifyApplication>(
    AppModule,
    new FastifyAdapter(),
  );
  app.register(fastifyHelmet)
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

try this instead. import fastifyHelmet from the package, use that to register.

Comment: This works for me while @Jay's answer doesn't.